# Unable to add ajax control tookit calender extender programatically

Tags: .net, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to add Calender control of AjaxControlToolkit but I am getting an error. 
The code and error are as follows:

```
    TableCell tc4 = new TableCell();

    TextBox txtSRVDate = new TextBox();
    tc4.Controls.Add(txtSRVDate);
    AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender calen = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
    calen.TargetControlID = "txtSRVDate";
    calen.Format = "dd/MM/yyy";

    tc4.Controls.Add(calen);
    tr2.Cells.Add(tc4);
    tblInwardRight.Rows.Add(tr2);
```

and the error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The TargetControlID of '' is not valid. A control with ID 'txtSRVDate' could not be found.

Can you tell me where Am I going wrong ?

Comment: Does the control txtSRVDAte exist in your page? Can you show your view code? In which event are you adding the calendar?

Comment: Ya..I figured out the problem. I did not set the ID of the textbox which the calen ControlID is referring to. Now, I set the ID of text box and now it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

The error is I did not set the ID of the textbox which the Ajaxcontrol calender control is referring to. I set the ID of the textbox and now the code is working fine..